# Apple Keychain Security Risk Assessment

Tags: password-management, apple

What security measures has Apple taken to minimize [security risk with respect to the Apple Keychain password manager](https://www.wired.com/story/keysteal-apple-keychain-attack-shenanigans/)?

I enjoy the capability of the password management across macOS and iOS devices, however, I would like to understand the mechanism so I can assess vulnerability risk.  Ultimately, I would like to understand Keychain risk and steps that I can take to mitigate risk

Comment: there's some documentation in this iOS whitepaper: https://www.apple.com/business/site/docs/iOS_Security_Guide.pdf